# JPA - EntityManagerFactory pointing to localhost

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I have following code. This code is responsible to connect to MySQL database from a remote location. But the issue is, the code is trying to connect to MySQL on localhost.

Actual exception received is:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost_ip' (using password: YES)

I am using Spring, JPA and hibernate in my project.

```
@Configuration("persistenceContext")
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
                    transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager",
                    basePackages = {"my.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceContext {

@Autowired
private DataSourcePropertyConfig dataSourcePropertyConfig;

public BasicDataSource datasource() {   
    final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(dataSourcePropertyConfig.getMySqlDriverClassName());
    dataSource.setUsername(dataSourcePropertyConfig.getMySqlDBUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(dataSourcePropertyConfig.getMySqlDBPassword());
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<database>");

    dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
    dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");

    return dataSource;
}

public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}


@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.datasource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("my.entity");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
}


@Bean(name = "jpaTransactionManager")
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
}
```

Regards
Anuj

Comment: Did u tried it with a hard coded username & password to know if it's working at the first level .. then we'll see what's the prob

Comment: yes, I did try with hard-coded username and passwords. But getting the same error.
 
 Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Comment: Issue was with the database user. Initially I had created a user like userrname@server_ip_address . Now i created a new user only as 'username'. Now able to connect with the database. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

> Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost_ip' (using password: YES)

does not indicate that you're connecting **to** a database on your localhost's IP address, it indicates that you're connecting **from** your localhost's IP address.

As to why you're getting the access denied error: most likely you don't have a user record in your database that matches `'my_user'@'localhost_ip'` or `'my_user'@'%'`.

Comment: I have created a user: adv_user@devAMX-AERAA004   Exception says: Access denied for user 'adv_user@de'@'my_ip' (using password: YES))

Comment: Issue was with the database user. Initially I had created a user like userrname@server_ip_address . Now i created a new user only as 'username'. Now able to connect with the database. Thanks for the pointers.